# Fortran - recompile program from 32bit to 64bit machine

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I've got really old program which I want to run on my 64bit computer. There are a lot of depreciated statements. During debugging I found that a lot of variables become NaN or Infinity... Hence, I changed variables from 4-bytes to 8-bytes long (i.e. REAL to REAL*8) but now caluclations and results are considerably different on both computers. Could somebody explain me if it really does matter if I use longer types and why on a 32-bit computer everything was OK but on a 64-bit one I get Infinity and NaN values?

P.S. I use *gfortran* compiler with `-fbackslash -ffixed-line-length-0 -std=legacy  -g -O0 -fno-inline` options

Regards,
kozooh

Comment: Are you using gfortran on both computers?

Comment: Nope, on 32-bit I use g77 compilator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to differences between the compilers and not between the bit-levels of the machines.  For example, some FORTRAN 77 compilers implicitly apply `save` to all procedure (subroutine and function) local variables.  This is not required by the standard and this behavior should not be relied upon.  It frequently causes problems when a legacy program is compiled with a modern compiler that demands that `save` be used if local variables should have their values retained across invocations of a procedure.   I don't know if g77 has this "feature".   You can turn on this behavior in gfortran with the compiler option `-fno-automatic`.

EDIT: consider:

```
  subroutine MySub
  logical FirstCall
  save FirstCall
  data FirstCall / .TRUE. /
  integer I

  if ( FirstCall ) then
     I = 0
     FirstCall = .FALSE.
  end if

  I = I + 1

  write (6, *) "Call", I

  end

  program main

  integer j

  do j=1, 4
     call MySub ()
  end do

  end program main
```

Compiled with g77 (no compiler options), the output is:

```
 Call 1
 Call 2
 Call 3
 Call 4
```

The local variable `I` is retaining its value across invocations of `MySub`.  So it appears that g77 is saving local variables even when not requested with `save`.  At least at the default optimization level.

Compiled with gfortran with options `fbackslash -ffixed-line-length-0 -std=legacy -g -O0 -fno-inline` the output is the same.     Now change to `-O3` and the output is:

```
 Call           1
 Call           2
 Call           3
 Call         129
```

Sometimes `I` retains its value, sometimes not.

Change one line of the program to: `save FirstCall, I` and the value is always retained:

```
 Call 1
 Call 2
 Call 3
 Call 4
```

Try `-fno-automatic` ...