# dyld no valid entry point

Tags: macos, fortran, dyld

I've recently upgraded my mac to 10.9 and having reinstalled Xcode and the command line tools I now get this error when I run g77:

```
g77 myprog.f -o myprog
./myprog
```

Gives the following error:

```
dyld: no valid entry point

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Does any one have any ideas what this means and how I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install `g77`? It looks like a library that `g77` uses has been updated/deleted. What does `otool -L /path/to/g77` say? I'd suggest a clean build of `g77`.

Comment: Or switch to gfortran.  gfortran will compile Fortran 77 using option `-ffixed-form`.  g77 hasn't been supported for many years.

Comment: `g77` is no longer maintained. You should get `gfortran` instead, as it will compile all F77 code.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I installed it using http://hpc.sourceforge.net. 

I've tried using gfortran and the code gives the wrong output (it's not my code) so I really need to stick to g77.

otool -L /usr/local/bin/g77 gives the following output:

usr/local/bin/g77:
 /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 88.3.4)

If anyone has any ideas that would be great - i'm in the middle of writing my phd thesis so really don't want to have to change the code, I just want it to work.

Comment: I've also run locate libSystem.B.dylib and get this: locate libSystem.B.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Does this suggest that g77 is using the wrong version of this library?

Comment: If you "need to stick to g77" (despite it being 8+ years since it was last updated/maintained), then you probably should look to downgrading to your previous OS version and hoping that it works the way it did before upgrading.

Comment: With gfortran, try the compiler option `-fno-automatic` and see if the output becomes correct.   See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880649/fortran-recompile-program-from-32bit-to-64bit-machine

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Still no joy with g77, i'm currently using a virtual box with an old version of ubuntu to run the code. That said, -fno-automatic seems to have worked! Thanks so much!